# Which Star Wars locations does the song "In the Empire" portray?

Tags: star-wars, music, phineas-and-ferb

The song "In the Empire" from *Phineas and Ferb: Star Wars* shows several locations that stormtroopers can visit by serving the Empire. Some, like Coruscant and Burbank are obvious. Are the others pre-existing *Star Wars* locations, or were they created for the special?

(At 0:44 and 1:45):

Comment: When I saw the title I was hoping it would be a parody set to the tune of ["In The Navy"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InBXu-iY7cw)...someone needs to put that together...

Comment: [In the Empire, you can sail the g'lactic seas. In the Empire, you can murder some Wookiees. In the Empire, In the Empiiiiire!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InBXu-iY7cw)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order of appearance;

- Endor
- Mustafar
- Tatooine desert
- Tantive IV
- On the back of a dewback (statue)
- Felucia (?)
- Mos Espa, Tatooine
- Tatooine (Concept art, [McQuarrie](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7b/53/98/7b5398875d4bd057400d587af5693bc9.jpg))
- Jedi Temple, Coruscant
- Burbank
- Death Star Hangar
- Tatooine desert
- Mos Eisley, Tatooine
- Geonosis
- Kashyyyk
- Dune Sea, Tatooine (?)
- Krayt dragon skeleton, Tatooine